# Facebook SDK for Python - getting all page likes of a Facebook profile

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using an access token from the Facebook Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), with access scope which includes user likes, I am using the following code to try to get all the likes of a user profile:

```
myfbgraph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
mylikes = myfbgraph.get_connections(id="me", connection_name="likes")['data']
for like in mylikes:
  print like['name'], like['category']
  ...
```

However this is always giving me only 25 likes, whereas I know that the profile I'm using has 42 likes.  Is there some innate limit operating here, or what's the problem in getting ALL the page likes of a user profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Graph documention:

> When you make an API request to a node or edge, you will usually not
>   receive all of the results of that request in a single response. This
>   is because some responses could contain thousands and thousands of
>   objects, and so most responses are paginated by default.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

Comment: I note there's a `paging` key in the `mylikes` dict, which is dict-valued and has a subkey called `next` with a value which is a URL.  I guess I have to use the `requests` library to make a second call, or can I just the `myfbgraph` object?  The lack of documentation is not nice, here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this appears to work (a method, which accepts a user's facebook graph):

```
def get_myfacebook_likes(myfacebook_graph):
   myfacebook_likes = []
   myfacebook_likes_info = myfacebook_graph.get_connections("me", "likes")

   while myfacebook_likes_info['data']:
     for like in myfacebook_likes_info['data']:
       myfacebook_likes.append(like)
     if 'next' in myfacebook_likes_info['paging'].keys():
       myfacebook_likes_info = requests.get(myfacebook_likes_info['paging']['next']).json()
     else:
       break

   return myfacebook_likes
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers will work, but pretty slowly for anything with many likes. If you just want the count for number of likes, you can get it much more efficiently with total_likes:

```
myfacebook_likes_info = graph.get_connections(post['id'], 'likes?summary=1')
print myfacebook_likes_info["summary"]["total_count"]
```